# How to do this transformation of complex rational function?

Tags: complex-analysis, rational-functions

[Here is a description of constructing Möbius map sending $1$, $i$, $-1$ to 0, 1, $\infty$, respectively](https://www.math.okstate.edu/~wrightd/INDRA/MobiusonCircles/node3.html)

$m(z) = \frac{(z-1)}{(z+1)} \frac{(i+1)}{(i-1)}$

I do not know how it was converted to :

$m(z) = -i \frac{(z-1)}{(z+1)} $

TIA

Comment: $(i+1) = -i\cdot (i-1)$.

Comment: @Daniel Fisher  Thx, it is more answer then comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to simplify a ratio of two complex numbers such as

$$\frac{a+bi}{c+di}$$

you should multiply the top and bottom by the complex conjugate of the denominator (this is a complex analogue of rationalising the denominator). By doing that we get

$$\frac{a+bi}{c+di}\frac{c-di}{c-di} = \frac{(a+bi)(c-di)}{c^2+d^2}$$

which can then be written in the form $x + yi$ for some real $x$ and $y$.

If you do this for the expression

$$\frac{1+i}{1-i}$$

you will find that it reduces to $-i$.

Comment: Thx. See also [wikibooks]        [1]:http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Computer_graphic_techniques/2D/plane#M.C3.B6bius_transformation